# Can a XCUIElement be tapped multiple times within an allotted timeframe?

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to test a button on an app that, when tapped 6 times in under a second, shows an alert tot he user, it's an easter egg of sorts. At first I tried to use `tap(withNumberOfTaps:numberOfTouches:)` but it's too slow, it taps 6 times in about 3 seconds.
I'm using Xcode 8.3.1 and iOS Simulator with iOS 10.3

Comment: Never used it but you might want to try this trick to increase the speed of your tests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282350/how-to-speed-up-ui-test-cases-in-xcode

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44114275/574449